# get the width between two parallel lines by a normal unit vector

Tags: vectors

I was watching a lecture. In that lecture, professor drew the following picture. He was saying, if **u** is a normal/perpendicular vector and **V** is a vector that's not perpendicular to the line, then the dot product of this two vector will be the distance/width between the two lines. Can any body explain it to me intuitively?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the definition of dot product as $$a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos \theta,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

If $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors, the required distance is $|V|\cos\theta=V\cdot u$, by definition of dot product, and the fact that $|u|=1$